# Issue in Excel Macro, does not transpose Number when Only 1 Row, only transpose if at least 2 Rows

Tags: excel, vba

sometimes this macro skipt the row, if there is only one line to transpose.
How to fix it`?

And it should transpose in the first line, where you have that numeric number. Currently it tranpose in the last line, after it detects all non-numberic number. I understood the problem but couldn't solve it so far.
Would be great if you can help me with your excel vba skills. Thanks a lot

```
Sub transposeNumbers()
    Dim c As Range, LastRow As Long, TopN As Long, LastN As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

    If IsNumeric(c.Offset(-1, 0)) = True Then
    
        TopN = c.Row
      
    Else
    
        If IsNumeric(c.Offset(1, 0)) = True Or c.Row = LastRow Then
        
            LastN = c.Row
            
            ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(TopN, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(LastN, 1)).Copy
            c.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        End If
    
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share screenshots of the before and the after?

Comment: Hello, I already updated it. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the target when you copy the data: Instead of `c.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial` you should use `ActiveSheet.Cells(TopN-1, 4).PasteSpecial`

Note that this solution does not work

- in case you have numbers in two successive rows.
- in case the last cells holds a numeric value.

And `with ActiveSheet` allows to reference the sheet directly via `.` while inside the `with` block.

```
Sub transposeNumbers()
Dim c As Range, LastRow As Long, TopN As Long, LastN As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        If IsNumeric(c.Offset(-1, 0)) = True Then
            TopN = c.Row
        End If
        If IsNumeric(c.Offset(1, 0)) = True Or c.Row = LastRow Then
            LastN = c.Row
            .Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(TopN, 1), .Cells(LastN, 1)).Copy
            .Cells(TopN-1, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next c
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, now it works thanks. But how to write that transpose line in the same line as the numeric row?

Comment: @teddy1995: Cange the target to `.Cells(TopN-1, 4).PasteSpecial`. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively scan the sheet from bottom to top, counting the non-numeric rows in each group (if any).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub transposeNumbers()

    Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long, cel As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set cel = .Cells(LastRow, "A")
        Do
            If Len(cel) > 0 And IsNumeric(cel) Then
                If n > 0 Then
                    cel.Offset(1).Resize(n).Copy
                    cel.Offset(, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
                End If
                n = 0
            Else
                n = n + 1
            End If
            If cel.Row = 1 Then Exit Do
            Set cel = cel.Offset(-1)
        Loop
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox LastRow & " rows processed", vbInformation

End Sub
```